# Merge two PO files and overwrite matching translation rules

Tags: merge, command-line-interface, translation, gnu, gettext

I'm attempting to merge two PO files.

I have a `base.po` file that has general translations.

I have an `extra.po` which has extra translations that I'd like to add to the base file OR overwrite translations for if there are matching translation IDs.

I've tried using `msgmerge`:

```
$ msgmerge extra.po base.po -o merge.po
```

But this comments out any translations with matching IDs.

Looking at the [`msgmerge` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msgmerge-Invocation.html), it doesn't look like there is any option to effect this behavior.

I'd like to be able to have multiple extra translation files (`extra1.po`, `extra2.po`, etc.) so I can merge them with the base translation file and use them in different contexts.

Does anyone know how to do what I'm attempting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out I needed to be using `msgcat` instead.

The below command creates a PO file `merge.po` that contains all of the translations from `extra.po` and adds any additional translations from `base.po`.

The `--use-first` option specifies that if there is a matching translation id between the two files, to choose the translation from `extra.po`.

```
$ msgcat extra.po base.po -o merge.po --use-first
```